# Scald get usage for an atom

Tags: 7, scald

In Drupal 7 with the [Scald](https://drupal.org/project/scald), is it possible to get the usage for a given atom, for example the nodes which are referencing it?

Answer (score 1):

There is a module for that https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/pascalt/2128697. It also has Views integration.

Comment: Note that this is now a full module at https://www.drupal.org/project/scald_index